# Routing to a specific tab using NGX-Bootstrap

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I'm working on a project, using Angular 6 with NGX-Bootstrap tabs.

What I'm trying to accomplish: Route to my tabs page from a different page, but to a specific tab. So far, I am able to navigate to the page with the tabs, with the correct path showing in the URL (/tabsPage#tab2), but it still lands on the first tab, and not the second.

**app.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('staticTabs') staticTabs: TabsetComponent;

this.route.fragment.subscribe((fragment: string) => {
  if(fragment){
    let id = this.staticTabs.tabs.findIndex(f => f.id == fragment);

    if(id > 0)
      this.staticTabs.tabs[id].active = true;
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<tabset #staticTabs>
  <tab id="tab1" heading="Tab 1"></tab>
  <tab id="tab2" heading="Tab 2"></tab>
  <tab id="tab3" heading="Tab 3"></tab>
</tabset>
```

**random-page.component.html**

```
<a [routerLink]="['/tabsPage']" fragment="tab2">Jump to Tab 2</a>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use query params. They are better suited and can be used as such:

```
  public ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.fragments.subscribe(
      (fragment) => { console.log(fragment) }
    );
  }
```

And in the html:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/a', { fragment: 'foo' }]">Jump to Tab A</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/b', { fragment: 'bar' }]">Jump to Tab B</a>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1738es

Comment: This seems like it could work. However, I'm a little confused on the implementation of the solution. Do I need to use queryParams for both the component with the tabs, as well as the component that will contain the link that will link to the tabs page?

Comment: You are specifying here how exactly you want to send data from link to component. In this case I want it as query params, so I subscribe to the query params of the activatedRoute in the component where I land. I realized that there is also an observable to fragments. so you are deciding in which observable the data will land.

In sum: yes, you want to specify it for both the link itself as well as the component which uses the value

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make a version of my original code work. My "this.route.fragment" had to be inside the subscribe/response for a function in my ngOnInit. I ended up using the following to route from **random-page.component.html**, to the second tab in **app.component.html**:

```
.subscribe(
  response => {
    this.setHouseWatchVehicle(response);

    this.router.navigate([
      `/housewatch/edit/${response.agency}-${response.watchYear}-${response.watchId}`
    ], this.navigationExtras);
  },
);
```

And then a function in the **app.component.ts** to call when the page is loaded:

```
fragmentTabs() {
  this.route.fragment.subscribe((fragment: string) => {
    if(fragment) {
      let id = this.staticTabs.tabs.findIndex(f => f.id == fragment);
      if(id > 0)
        this.staticTabs.tabs[id].active = true;
    }
  });
}
```